Get Jenkins Job Build ID from Queue ID, while job is still in queue
I can get the list of builds in queue from this URL, https://api.jenkins.io//queue/api/json and then I can use the queue id and get more details about it from https://api.jenkins.io//queue/item/123/api/json. But it will not have the build number while the job is still in queue. I can see the build number assigned in UI, need help to fetch it from API.
